# Is it possible to know last user activity from a Windows service?

Tags: c++, winapi, service, user-activity

I have a Windows service program (written using C++) that is required to perform an energy saving power operation at a certain time of the day. I need to find out if a user might be at the terminal at the time when the power operation is performed and if he/she is, postpone it then. So my question is, how do you know the moment of the last user activity from a Windows service (running as a local system)?

PS. By user activity I mean keyboard and mouse activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user session will have to run a background app within its session that communicates with the service, then the app can report the last activity time so the service can make decisions based on that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. But there are two issues: 1. (Major one) Will that still be possible to do in Windows 8 and Metro interface when the desktop is just an app? 2. What if we have a Remote session, or in case a user hit Ctrl+Alt+Del and sees a logon screen -- I don't think one can run a background app in that session?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how deterministic it has to be, you could use the task scheduler. It can trigger the task when the computer is idle, wait for a while for it to be, etc. You can add the task manually to begin, then [use the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[image: Task Scheduler power settings]

Answer (score 0):

In a rare case of Microsoft actually providing the API function that you need, you can use GetLastInputInfo().

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if called by a service because the service is running in a different session from the user. This method will always return 0 unless it's called from a console session.

Comment: JRiggles, you are correct.